# How can I disable Zip link in HTML publisher plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using HTML publisher plugin for Jenkins. I saw that there is a link on the top right corner of the page which downloads the zip file for the entire report folder.
Is there any way I can modify what to download and what not from there?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem everey now and then (I guess when an update is installed automatically by jenkins).

After reading [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy) (in particular the section *HTML Publisher Plugin*) I found the following. I executed the groovy script below using the script console:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'unsafe-inline'; ")
System.getProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP")
```